# Angular 12 Material table 'mat-row' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am using `Angular 12` and `"@angular/material": "^12.2.9",`

My `module.t`s is like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ConnectorCommonRoutingModule } from './connector-common-routing.module';
import { NotificationsComponent } from './components/notification/notification.component';
import {MatTableModule,MatTableDataSource,} from '@angular/material/table';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NotificationsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MatTableDataSource,
    MatTableModule,
    CommonModule,
    ConnectorCommonRoutingModule

  ]
})
export class ConnectorCommonModule { }
```

In my .html I have this table like this

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="full-width-table">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Active">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Active</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let not">{{not.Active}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="NotificationName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Notification Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let not">{{not.NotificationName}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="ProcessorName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Processor Name</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let not">{{not.ProcessorName}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="ChannelAndLevel">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Channel & Level</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let not">{{not.ChannelAndLevel}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>

  </mat-table>
```

When i run `ng serve` got this error...

> If 'mat-row' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of
> this module.

I have read to import this

```
import { AngularMaterialModule } from './../angular-material/angular-material.module';
```

but this does not exists..

What reference i am missing to import?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`MatTableDataSource` is angular material class [see doc.](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api). You cann't import it in the import array because it is not a module. Remove it from the imports array.

If you want to use it, simply import and use it like other classes in your component `ts` files as:

`import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';`

`this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);`

[see stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cy8oji?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.ts)